# Derivative of eigenvalues

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I work with **4x4 Hermitian matrices (r)**. I want to calculate a derivative of a function f[t,r] (ff[t_,r_]=1/2*D[f[t,r],t]), where the function f depends on the absolute value of the eigenvalues of r. Unfortunately, I have failed (for example ff[1,some random r] doesn't give me any numerical value). How should I change my code? Are the eigenvalues I calculate obtained analytically (this should be possible for 4x4 matrices)?

Keep in mind, that **r is a 4x4 matrix!!!**

```
sx = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
sy = {{0, I}, {-I, 0}};
Mapp1[t_, r_] := 
  1/2*(1 + Exp[-t])*r + 
   1/2*(1 - Exp[-t])*
    KroneckerProduct[sx, sy].r.KroneckerProduct[sx, sy];
Eigenvalue1[t_, r_] := 
  Eigenvalues[Mapp1[t, r], Cubics -> True, Quartics -> True][[1]];
Eigenvalue2[t_, r_] := 
  Eigenvalues[Mapp1[t, r], Cubics -> True, Quartics -> True][[2]];
Eigenvalue3[t_, r_] := 
  Eigenvalues[Mapp1[t, r], Cubics -> True, Quartics -> True][[3]];
Eigenvalue4[t_, r_] := 
  Eigenvalues[Mapp1[t, r], Cubics -> True, Quartics -> True][[4]];
f[t_, r_] := Sqrt[Eigenvalue1[t, r]^2] +
   Sqrt[Eigenvalue2[t, r]^2] + Sqrt[Eigenvalue3[t, r]^2] + 
   Sqrt[Eigenvalue4[t, r]^2];
ff[t_, r_] = 1/2*D[f[t, r], t]
```

Comment: `Eigenvalues[Mapp1[t, r]]` returns unevaluated, because `Mapp1[t, r]` is not a matrix.  Maybe you're missing `()` around `1/2*(1 + Exp[-t])*r + 1/2*(1 - Exp[-t])`?  And `KroneckerProduct[sx, sy].r.KroneckerProduct[sx, sy]` isn't a matrix either.

Comment: If r is a 4x4 matrix, then both Mapp1[t, r] and KroneckerProduct[sx, sy].r.KroneckerProduct[sx, sy] are 4x4 matrices.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I used a number.

Comment: Does changing the definition of `ff` to `ff[t_, r_] := 1/2*D[f[t, r], t]` work?

Comment: No, it makes it even worse, as the value of t will be set in before the Mathematica applies the derivative.

Comment: Agnieszka, it is not so easy to guess, that `r` has to be a $4 \times 4$ matrix. Please add example data to your post.

Comment: Is this better? `ff[t_, r_] := Block[{s}, D[f[s, r], s] /. s -> t] `

Comment: Hm, it seems to work, though I do not understand the syntax... Are ff calculated analytically or numerically?

Comment: @Agnieszka Don’t forget 1/2, use  `ff[t_, r_] := Block[{s}, D[f[s, r], s] /. s -> t]/2`. For a given `r`, function `f [t,r] ` is an analytic function of t (check this). You can also use `ff = 1/2*D[f[t, r], t]` but must determine `r` before.

Comment: But for ff[t,r] and r hermitian I get a complex number, with very small imaginary part. Isn't then so, that ff is calculated numerically? It should be real when r is hermitian...